# mysql time comparison - strange result

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I use a timestamp field that is set with current time when inserts.

It has the following entries.

```
    6   2011-02-10 09:36:31     174.129.228.67
    4   2011-02-10 09:36:36     174.129.228.67
    5   2011-02-10 09:36:41     174.129.228.67
    4   2011-02-10 12:11:08     192.168.0.4
    6   2011-02-10 12:48:21     192.168.0.22
    1   2011-02-10 12:48:45     192.168.0.22
    2   2011-02-10 12:49:00     192.168.0.22
    2   2011-02-10 12:49:01     66.220.158.251
    6   2011-02-10 12:49:18     66.220.158.251
    5   2011-02-10 13:00:25     66.220.149.249
```

Now() is

2011-02-10 17:20:04

When I execute,
select * from list where timestampField > (now()-(8*60*60))

It return empty result set. Here, I expect entries entered after 2011-02-10 9:20:04.

When I execute,
select * from list where timestampField > (now()-(14*60*60))

I get,

```
1   2011-02-10 12:48:45     192.168.0.22
2   2011-02-10 12:49:00     192.168.0.22
2   2011-02-10 12:49:01     66.220.158.251
6   2011-02-10 12:49:18     66.220.158.251
```

Why this. Could you tell me what is the proper way to get entries of previous hours.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot subtract seconds from time in mysql. You need to use a function like this:

```
WHERE dateadded > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 8 HOUR)
```

Comment: how come it returns for some values and some values, not. Any mention in the manual.

Comment: Because if you use `-` to subtract from a `now()` value you are substracting from a value like `20110210131151.000000`. So if you subtract a large amount like 14*60*60 you get `20110210080831.000000`. It is less, but not 14 hours less.

Comment: it doesn't throw errors either. However urs works fine. THanks.

Comment: maths using text, not fine. what do u think?

Comment: It depends, in mysql's case I think it really helps producing readable queries. Also, because it is time, there really isn't a standard math for time based operations.